# Как сделать изменение размера окна в framelees window

Tags: c++, qt

Я новичек в qt. Нашел вариант сделать это через qsizegrip, но когда добавляю его к qmainwindow то просто создается какая-то кнопка слева-сверху, а мне нужно сделать просто так, чтобы можно было увеличивать/уменьшать размер окна через границу окна (как раз это qsizegrip не реализует простым его созданием, либо нужно переопределить какие-то эвенты)

У меня была ситуация, когда я сам пытался сделать qundostack, потому-что не знал о его существовании, думаю, с qsizegrip та же ситуация и не хотелось бы писать велосипед. Покажите пожалуйста реализацию того, что я хочу

up